# Unable to view or edit the files in ms office software from our web app using ActiveX control

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, internet-explorer-11, activex, document-view

I have Microsoft office integration with my web application where there is option to view and edit the uploaded files by clicking on an edit button which opens the file in the appropriate Microsoft software. Such as if a word file is uploaded then on clicking the edit button, the file should get opened in the Microsoft word software. I am using ActiveX controls for this functionality for opening the document using the below code on IE,

spEditObj.EditDocument(FileURL);

I have verified the FileURL is correct as on clicking the edit button, the breakpoint control was coming here where this FileURL value is coming correct and this function [ spEditObj.EditDocument(FileURL) ] is returning true value but still the file content is not being displayed.

The issue is that when I am clicking on the edit button, its opening the Microsoft word application but **the file content is not being displayed**.

I am guessing that it is due to improper installation of MS office or may be due to missing some dll files.

Can you please suggest me the fix for this ?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file permission, whether you have permission to read and write it.

I have create a sample using the following code, it works well on my machine, you could refer to it:

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function () { 
            $('a').on('click', function () {
                var file = $(this).attr('href');

                // This is what does the work.
                try {
                    try {
                        // get Word Active-X Object if Word is open.
                        var word = GetObject('', "Word.Application");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        // create new Word Active-X Object.
                        var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
                    }

                    word.Visible = true; // Make sure Word is visible.
                    word.Documents.Open(file); // Open the file you want.
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e.description);
                }
                // End work.

                return false;
            });
        }); 
    </script>
    <a href="<local file path>">Readiness.docx</a>
```

[Note]we need to enable the Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting (IE browser Tools Menu -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level -> enable the Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting), please check and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. this issue seems to be due to authentication problem for the WebDAV Directory. Resolved it on my own by changing the authentication of the WebDAVDir from basic authentication to windows authentication from Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.